# Cache in app purchase or check on each start on Android app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a few in app purchases for my app, each unlocking certain sections of the app.

Which would be the best way of actually having the purchase status in the app, but in a right way?:

1. Store the purchase, after the actual purchase or on restore purchases, on `SharedPreferences` and read it on app start. This could create problems: in case of a refund, the app would continue to have the values. A rooted user could edit the xml and add the purchase as it if was made.
2. perform on app's startup a `queryInventoryAsync` and store the result as SharedPreference for future use in the app. This would allow, in case of no network, to use the SharedPreference value from the previous `queryInventoryAsync` results.

> Because the Google Play client now caches In-app Billing information
>   locally on the device, you can use the Version 3 API to query for this
>   information more frequently, for example through a getPurchases call.
>   Unlike with previous versions of the API, many Version 3 API calls
>   will be serviced through cache lookups instead of through a network
>   connection to Google Play, which significantly speeds up the API's
>   response time.

So what to do? Would `queryInventoryAsync` on each app startup create any issues given that it should use cached results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `queryInventoryAsync`on each app startup in all of my games and so far there has been no issues (20k users).

Comment: Thank you. Are you also storing the results in case `queryInventoryAsync` fails?

Comment: No i don't store the results in case it fails

Comment: I don't store the results separately either. One thing I've noticed though is that users often complain the app doesn't recognise previous in-app purchases after an app upgrade. So I suspect the cache is cleared during the upgrade, and if the app can't then query Google's servers in time then the app may temporarily show the purchase as not having been made.